# Joomla: Existing session variables are gone after login

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a multi page form in a component. It's for the user not necessary to log in at first. But if they want to save the result they need to log in at one point.

I save the model in a session so I can access it on any page:

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set( 'model', serialize($model) );
```

and read it out with:

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession(); 
$model = unserialize($session->get( 'model', 'empty' ));
```

This works well, but if I login on the page the current session is cleared and only filled with log in information afterwards.

I checked different sources but the only thing what I find is that the session is cleared at log out, but not at log in.

Can anybody tell my where this behavior comes from? And how I can fix it?

Comment: I found out a trick to get it working, but still confused by this behavior.

It have all to do with the return value in the loginform. If this is set to a "self made link" it's not working. But if this is set to joomla self made links it is:

index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview

Most likely it has to do with the order of execution, maybe I try to get my model from a session when it's not available yet. Feel free to contribute a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid the issue in the first place and use a cookie?  You can read and write cookies directly on the backend if you want so you don't have to rewrite any logic beyond the saving/ reading of the cookies.

Comment: because the price is saved in this model, and I don't want to save this to a cookie. The price is in there so I'm sure the user is paying the price which he saw at the moment of order. If the price is changing in the database while ordering it's not affecting this specific user.